# Ignore fields only in XML but not json in spring boot (xml Mapper)

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson, fasterxml

How to ignore some fields while converting POJO to XML using `XMLMapper` but not in JSON.

```
public String getXmlInString(String rootName, Object debtReport) {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    return xmlMapper.writer().withRootName(rootName).withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(debtReport);
}
```

POJO Class

```
Class Employee {
    Long id;
    String name;
    LocalDate dob;
}
```

The expected output in JSON

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Thirumal",
"dob": "02-04-1991"
}
```

The expected output in XML (Need to ignore `ID`)

```
<Employee>
<name>Thirumal</name>
<dob>02-04-1991</dob>
</Employee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [JsonView](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html)

First declare Views class with two "profiles" - default (only `Default` fields are serialized) and json-only (both `Default` and `Json` fields are serialized):

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Json extends Default {
    }
    public static class Default {
    }
}
```

Then mark always visible fields with `Default`-view and ID field with `Json` view:

```
public class Employee {
    @JsonView(Views.Json.class)
    Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.Default.class)
    String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Default.class)
    String dob;
}
```

Then instruct mapper to respect given appropriate view during serialization:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.id = 1L;
    emp.name = "John Doe";
    emp.dob = "1994-03-02";

    // JSON with ID
    String json = new ObjectMapper()
            .writerWithView(Views.Json.class)
            .writeValueAsString(emp);

    System.out.println("JSON: " + json);


    // XML without ID
    String xml = new XmlMapper()
            .writerWithView(Views.Default.class)
            .writeValueAsString(emp);

    System.out.println("XML: " + xml);
}
```

Finally the output is:

```
JSON: {"id":1,"name":"John Doe","dob":"1994-03-02"}
XML: <Employee><name>John Doe</name><dob>1994-03-02</dob></Employee>
```